# Login screen while accessing wcf from silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0, wcf-security

I have a Silverlight 4 application which gets data from a silverlight enabled WCF service and using binding(basichttp). Sometimes when we open the silverlight application windows login screen appears it asks for username and password but we haven't enabled such things from code. I tried to add some config settings for the WCF service but unable to solve so.

Comment: It's probably UAC asking for permission to perform requested operation.

Comment: does IIS has windows authentication enabled?

Comment: windows authentication is enabled..

Comment: Does it have anything to do with configurations in web.config/client config????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Think I got near to Solution as my WCF service was not able to send large amount of data to my silverlight application so the connection between both terminates regularly resulting in the Login Screen to appear(tries to reconnect). After increasing the '' inside the behaviours tag in the web.config i.e setting the max value for the "maxItemsInObjectGraph" solved my issue and that login screen just dissappeared.

Hope this Helps.

Regards,
Zafar

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, use `Ntlm` authentication to the WCF service instead of `Windows`. This problem will normally appear when you run the service under a non-domain (i.e. a machine) account.

For more details, check this MSDN article: *[Debugging Windows Authentication Errors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463274.aspx)* (to make it easier to read, think of Kerboros and Windows authentication as being synonymous).